# firebase cli serve cant access the project from different device

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have install firebase cli etcetc. I can start the project and develop using firebase serve. I can visit the page of the project through localhost:5000 but if i try from different device in my network (mobile phone) to access network-ip:5000 I get connection refused.

Anyone knows what configuration/command it needs to forward port 5000 ? (different projects like creat-react-app works fine)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
firebase serve -o 0.0.0.0
```

The `-o` flag sets the host.

For more information, see [Server Fault: What's the difference between IP address 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1?](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1)

Answer (score 3):

With a local IP 192.168.0.10
I launched `firebase serve -o 192.168.0.10` and it works perfectly on port 5000 from other device

In my javascript app :
functions.useFunctionsEmulator('http://192.168.0.10:5000')

Answer (score 2):

If you run `firebase serve --help`, it will give you the information needed to listen on a different port or IP address:

```
Usage: serve [options]

start a local server for your static assets

Options:

-p, --port <port>   the port on which to listen (default: 5000) (default: 5000)
-o, --host <host>   the host on which to listen (default: localhost) (default: localhost)
--only <targets>    only serve specified targets (valid targets are: functions, hosting)
--except <targets>  serve all except specified targets (valid targets are: functions, hosting)
-h, --help          output usage information
```

You can use -p and -o on the command line to change the host and port where it listens for connections.  For your case, you won't be able use localhost for the host because that's only visible to other processes on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/346) worked for me. I found the config.json file for the functions-emulator (It's in user/.config/configstore/@googlecloud/functions-emulator/config.json on mac or windows) and changed "bindHost": "localhost", to "bindHost": "0.0.0.0" and then I could access served functions from other devices on my network via localip:5000 which wasn't working before.

> Tivoli commented on Aug 20, 2017 •
>
> Digging around the code I figured this out, it's because the
>   firebase-tools is only setting the projectId as part of the
>   functions-emulator config. This fixes it in my Dockerfile
>
> ADD config.json
>   /root/.config/configstore/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/config.json
>
> and the config.json looks like this
>
> {
>   "bindHost": "0.0.0.0" }
>
> You can change the 0.0.0.0 to any host you want, but this works for
>   Docker.
>
> For reference
>   https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/lib/serve/functions.js#L71
>   is the offending block, it needs to set the above parameter to the
>   same as the --host command line parameter.
>
> If you are running on your own local machine then you need to set it
>   to the configstore folder for your respective OS on OS X it would be
>   ~/.config/configstore/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/config.json.
>
> Reference for the default config values
>   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/blob/master/src/defaults.json