# Access firebase emulator from local network

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm using `firebase emulators:start` firebase command to emulate functions locally. This work fine on iOS simulator but if I use real android device which is in the same network, these functions are unreachable. I can access `5001` port like this: `locahost:5001` but not like this: `192.168.x.x:5001`.

I have the following code in my react-native expo project:

```
export const functions = firebase.functions();
firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://192.168.x.x:5001');
```

but again, this only works on a simulator if I change the last line to:

```
firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
```

Is it possible to start the emulator with something like `--host` option like in `firebase serve` command? Is there any other solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [firebase cli serve cant access the project from different device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769168/firebase-cli-serve-cant-access-the-project-from-different-device)

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate. `firebase serve` is not the same as firebase `emulators:start`.

Comment: I still can't see any difference between the two questions focusing on the main goal and there is a good answer to.

Comment: That answer does not apply to my question. There is no `-o` option in `firebase emulators:start`

Comment: @KingJulien Did you every figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @Conner Nope, unfortunately they do not support this feature yet.

Comment: @KingJulien Actually I figured it out yesterday haha... set "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    }
  }

Comment: I can't even make it work for iOS simulator, which post do you use for simulator to connect?

Answer (score 74):

Set your firebase.json to

```
"emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    }
  }
```

The "0.0.0.0" host tells your computer to use localhost and your local ip for your network at the same time

Check Android FirebaseDatabase library changelog (version 19.1.0 explains this new feature) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/6ae83de756628b933c7ddaf1153c14af0315c945/firebase-database/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: In my case, I have to set it to my local IP to work.

Comment: Right answer - explained here in the official docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy

Answer (score 8):

To listen on a different host than the `default: localhost` just check the `--help`

```bash
$ firebase serve --help
Usage: serve [options]

start a local server for your static assets

Options:

-p, --port <port>   the port on which to listen (default: 5000) (default: 5000)
-o, --host <host>   the host on which to listen (default: localhost) (default: localhost)
--only <targets>    only serve specified targets (valid targets are: functions, hosting)
--except <targets>  serve all except specified targets (valid targets are: functions, hosting)
-h, --help          output usage information
```

In this case:

```
firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://0.0.0.0:5001');
```

or

```
firebase serve -o 0.0.0.0
```

Because `0.0.0.0` means [*Current network (only valid as source address).*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Special-use_addresses)

Comment: The cause of the `firebase serve` in my answer: *"Is it possible to start the emulator with something like `--host` option like in `firebase serve` command?"*

Comment: `firebase serve` is now deprecated; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618725/firebase-serve-only-functions-vs-local-emulator-to-run-cloud-functions-locally

Answer (score 1):

To build on Conner's answer - if you're testing on a physical device, you'll have a better time connecting using your computer's IP address. Rather than hardcoding it, you can use a built-in variable: `Constants.manifest.debuggerHost?.split(":").shift()`.

Wrote up a short explanation on that here:

https://dev.to/haydenbleasel/using-the-firebase-local-emulator-with-expo-s-managed-workflow-5g5k