# ConnectFirestoreEmulator() throwing Connection WebChannel transport errored

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-tools

I have a react native app, which i am developing using Expo. In my project, i run firebase firestore emulator and I want to connect my application to the emulator. I use the expo GO app on my phone and call the following function (after initialising the app):

```
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "127.0.0.1", 8080);
```

When i try to add data to the firestore using:

```
const joinDesqr = await addDoc(colRef, {
        userID: userID,
        level: level,
        timeslots: timeslots,
        days: days,
      })
```

i get a warning like this, and the data is not inserted to the firestore emulator database:

```
 WARN  [2023-02-21T17:29:08.454Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.1): Connection WebChannel transport errored: {"defaultPrevented": false, "g": {"A": true, "J": null, "R": [Circular], "g": {"$": true, "$a": 5000, "A": 0, "B": null, "C": 0, "Ca": null, "D": "gsessionid", "Ea": -1, "F": [U], "Fa": 0, "G": 0, "Ga": false, "H": true, "Ia": [ud], "J": "", "K": undefined, "L": false, "M": true, "O": true, "P": false, "R": 0, "U": [Object], "V": -1, "W": 70081, "Y": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "aa": 0, "ab": false, "ba": false, "bb": false, "cb": 2, "eb": 1, "fb": 10000, "g": null, "h": [pd], "i": [Array], "j": [Sb], "l": [Z], "la": [Object], "m": null, "ma": undefined, "na": null, "o": null, "oa": null, "s": null, "sa": 0, "u": null, "ua": undefined, "v": null, "va": null, "wa": 600000}, "h": {"database": "projects/padel-q/databases/(default)"}, "i": {"g": [Object], "h": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "j": {"g": [Circular]}, "l": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "o": undefined, "s": false, "v": true}, "status": 1, "target": {"A": true, "J": null, "R": [Circular], "g": {"$": true, "$a": 5000, "A": 0, "B": null, "C": 0, "Ca": null, "D": "gsessionid", "Ea": -1, "F": [U], "Fa": 0, "G": 0, "Ga": false, "H": true, "Ia": [ud], "J": "", "K": undefined, "L": false, "M": true, "O": true, "P": false, "R": 0, "U": [Object], "V": -1, "W": 70081, "Y": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "aa": 0, "ab": false, "ba": false, "bb": false, "cb": 2, "eb": 1, "fb": 10000, "g": null, "h": [pd], "i": [Array], "j": [Sb], "l": [Z], "la": [Object], "m": null, "ma": undefined, "na": null, "o": null, "oa": null, "s": null, "sa": 0, "u": null, "ua": undefined, "v": null, "va": null, "wa": 600000}, "h": {"database": "projects/padel-q/databases/(default)"}, "i": {"g": [Object], "h": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "j": {"g": [Circular]}, "l": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "o": undefined, "s": false, "v": true}, "type": "c"}
```

If i don't run the `ConnectFirebaseEmulator()` function, the application perfectly adds data to my real firestore database. My reasoning is that i should put the IP of my actual computer where the local emulator is running. The default value is "localhost" instead, which is not working either.

I have tried experimentalForceLongPolling as some threads suggest, but without success:

```
const db = initializeFirestore(firebaseConfig, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
});
```

Comment: As your firebase emulator is running on your computer but your application is running on separate device so Obviously localhost will not work as firebase emulator is not running on expo device. If possible can you also share your `firebase.json` file as that needs to be configured like provided in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260877/access-firebase-emulator-from-local-network)